# Angular moving CRUD functions to service

Tags: angular

I'm struggling to migrate my CRUD functions to a service, which is where I feel like they belong. I think this has to do with my lack of understanding of `map` and `subscribe` etc.

**My 'get' function**

```
getClients() : Observable<Client[]> {
  return this.authService.get('clients')
    .map(res => res.json())
    .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
};
```

This is an HTTPWrapper provided by Angular2-Token. It works exactly as posted in the component with expected results. However, I want to move it to the `client service`

**Service**

```
import { Injectable }     from '@angular/core';
import { Client }     from '../client/client';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

// Import RxJs required methods
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import { Angular2TokenService } from "angular2-token";

@Injectable()
export class ClientService{

  constructor(private authToken: Angular2TokenService) {
  }

    getClients() : Observable<Client[]> {
      return this.authToken.get('clients')
        .map(res => res.json())
        .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
    };
}
```

I then modify my component to resemble

```
  constructor(private clientService: ClientService) { }
  clients: Client[];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.clientService.getClients();
  }

  getClients() : Observable<Client[]> {
    return this.clientService.getClients();
  }
```

And now I receive an Uncaught error every page load, but the compilation works.

I do believe this is because I'm over-simplifying it, but I'm unsure how to appropriately 'subscribe' to it for the component.

Do I `.map()` the `res` and then subscribe within the component?

**Update Based on Comments**

**Service**

```
import { Injectable }     from '@angular/core';
import { Client }     from '../client/client';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

// Import RxJs required methods
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import { Angular2TokenService } from "angular2-token";

@Injectable()
export class ClientService{

  constructor(private authToken: Angular2TokenService) {
  }

  getClients() {
    this.authToken.get('clients')
      .map(res => res.json())
      .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
  };

}
```

**Component**

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Client } from "./client";
import { Angular2TokenService } from "angular2-token";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { ClientService } from "../services/client.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-client',
  templateUrl: './client.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./client.component.sass']
})
export class ClientComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private
                // authService: Angular2TokenService
  clientService: ClientService
  ) {
  }

  clients: Client[];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getClients();
  }

  getClients() : Observable<Client[]> {
    this.clientService.getClients()
      .subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res)
      });
  }

  // getClients(): Observable<Client[]> {
  //   this.authService.get('clients')
  //     .map(res => res.json()).subscribe(
  //       res => this.clients = res,
  //       error => console.log(error)
  //     );
  // }
};
```

I do have it required. I currently am getting 3 errors (2 on service and 1 on component) that `a function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.`

Last time just 'returning' the value in component resolved it, but unsure what the service should look like.

Comment: you are doing map because you need json from response and that is correct just subscribe to it in your component and it should work.

Comment: Why was I down-voted? I am asking a specific question, with both examples of what I have done, and my code-base.

Comment: Upvoted because question was given correct details, also because I experienced this rxjs beginner's mistake myself at the time. IMHO A programming mistake caused by a very simple error doesn't mean the question is bad / deserved to be downvoted .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to subscribe to getClients method to see results

e.g

```
this.clientService.getClients().subscribe((data) => console.log(data));
```

or as you are doing

```
constructor(private clientService: ClientService) { }
  clients: Client[];

ngOnInit() {
  this.clientService.getClients().subscribe((data) => {
  console.log(data);
},(err) => {
  console.log(err);
});
}

getClients() : Observable<Client[]> {
   return this.clientService.getClients();
}
```

Comment: @joraway-singh How do I modify the function I moved from the component to the service? It isn't working out of the box due to a `properly or signature` error.

Comment: have you your service declared in providers in your module like providers:[ClientService]?

Comment: Thanks - I think I get it. For some reason subscribing within the `getClients()` was giving me an issue, but moving it to the `ngOnInit` seemed to have resolved it. I think I get how subscribing works now.

Thanks.

Comment: @DNorthrup glad it sorted out for you :-)

Answer (score 1):

You Just need to `subscribe` to your observable in order to get desired output like this, also i think you need to change this in your component

```
constructor(private clientService: ClientService) { }
  clients: Client[];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getClients();
  }

  getClients() : {
        this.clientService.getClients()
           .subscribe(res => {
              console.log(res)
           });
      }
```

> Do I .map() the res and then subscribe within the component?

`.map()` return observable from the stream and then you return `.json()` format from the map() function , In order to get Response in the component level from the service you need to subscribe to that Observable.